# How in ruby do you loop through the contents of a .csv file and verify its contents?

Tags: ruby, csv

Currently I have a csv file that resembles:

```
    1%,    2%,    3%,    4%, 
1m, $1.00, $1.50, $2.75, $3.00
2m, $1.25, $1.10, $2.00, $3.50
```

I am trying to check every permutation for the appropriate dollar amount. Mostly I am having a problem finding an angle to tackle this from. My sloppy code looks like the following. I am 99% sure I am going about this the wrong way.

```
CSV.foreach("some.csv") do |row|
@row = row.to_s
  if @row.include?('%')
    percent_char = []
    percent_char.push(@row)
 end
  if @row.include?('m')
    m_char = []
    m_char.push(@row)
  end
end

m_char.each do |m|
percent_char.each do |percent|
puts "Increment m_char #{m} and increment #{percent}" 
#per increment I want to be able to assert the proper dollar amount
#this will assert true no matter what, but would just like to learn how to get here
assert_equals(dollar, dollar)
end
end
```

I have a placeholder here for 'dollar' primarily just to illustrate what I am trying to achieve. Might anyone have any ideas how I should go about this?

Comment: You are reassigning `m_char` and `percent_char` every time you find a match. You probably don't want to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking for something like this?

```
CSV.foreach('some.csv', headers: true) do |row|
  m_char = nil
  row.each do |percent, dollar|
    if m_char
      # whatever kind of validation you wanted goes here
    else
      m_char = dollar
    end
  end
end
```

But this will only work if you fix your CSV file. You're missing a value in the first row, so the percents don't line up right. You need an extra comma:

```
  ,    1%,    2%,    3%,    4%
1m, $1.00, $1.50, $2.75, $3.00
2m, $1.25, $1.10, $2.00, $3.50
```